# Как связать таблицы в MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день объясните люди добрые мне одну вещь. Как связываются между собой две таблицы в БД? Для чего это нужно ?? и как делать индексацию таблиц ?? буду очень признателен если дадите развернутое описание что и как делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нормализация.**

Предлагаю ознакомится с таким понятием, как [нормализация БД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) ([1НФ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), [2НФ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)...). Всё это необходимо для подавления избыточности - данные должны быть атомарны в рамках кортежа (записи) и атрибута (столбца).

В высоконагруженных проектах в борьбе за производительность, нормализацией искусственно пренебрегают. Таким образом, увеличивается объём отдельно взятой сущности в пользу сокращения "многоэтажности" запросов. Несомненно, необходимо проверить, стоит ли овчинка выделки и задуматься о правильности архитектуры.

**Типы связей.**

2-ая НФ и последующие декларируют именно это.

- 1:1 (один-ко-одному) - частный случай типа связи 1:М. В общем случае, есть не что иное, как атрибут (столбец);
- 1:M (один-ко-многим) - примером может служить заданный Вами вопрос на хэшкоде и множество ответов к нему;
- М:М ([многим-ко-многим](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/msdn/r.php?117)) - система тегирования на хэшкоде.

Для связи двух и более таблиц принято использовать оператор [**Join**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

**Индексация.**

> Индекс — объект базы данных, создаваемый с целью повышения производительности поиска данных (источник: [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%28%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%29)).

Для всех тех атрибутов (столбцов), которые указаны в условии запроса [WHERE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29), необходимо добавить индекс для быстрого поиска. Добавление индекса влечёт за собой накладные расходы на объём, потому такой выборочный подход.

Один из механизмов добавление индекса с помощью веб-клиента phpMyAdmin:
[image]

Все тонкости составных индексов и при использовании оператора LIKE я Вам оставляю на самостоятельное изучение.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join

Answer (score 0):

http://bd.gym5cheb.ru/p7aa1.html